# Service is not starting

Tags: android, service, stream, background-process

I have written a service which is streaming a url. There is a twitter button that only open a link with browser. when I clicked to this button however I start the service in the button event, it is not starting. My Service's codes are here;

```
public class MyMediaPlayerService extends Service implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
    OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private String path = "http://someUrl.m3u8";
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private static final String MEDIA = "media";;
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {

        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public void onPause() {
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    doCleanUp();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.getMetadata();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
}
```

also I have started the service in the button event like this;

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/standart_fm"));
            Intent svc = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MyMediaPlayerService.class);
            //startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            startService(svc);
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
```

The log cat is;

```
07-31 14:44:15.392: D/Vitamio[Player](562): THREAD AUDIO_OUTPUT END
07-31 14:44:15.419: D/Vitamio[Player](562): THREAD AUDIO_DECODE END
07-31 14:44:15.440: I/Vitamio[Player](562): CLOSE STREAM AUDIO END
07-31 14:44:15.440: I/Vitamio[Player](562): CLOSE AVFORMAT BEGIN
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): CLOSE AVFORMAT END
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE VIDEOPIC BEGIN
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE VIDEOPIC 2 END
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE SUBPIC BEGIN
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE SUBPIC 1 END
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE AUDIOFRAME BEGIN
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FREE AUDIOFRAME 8 END
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): DELETE GLOBAL REF BEGIN
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): DELETE GLOBAL REF END
07-31 14:44:15.450: I/Vitamio[Player](562): FILE CLOSE END
07-31 14:44:15.450: D/Vitamio[Player](562): THREAD NOTIFY END
07-31 14:44:15.460: I/Vitamio[Player](562): VPLAYER RELEASE END
```

So. How can i run the stream with this service when twitter activity has started?

Comment: What is the output of logcat?

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing the startService and stepping through the route? I'd be interested to see if it is just silently failing or whether there is something else going on. The logcat doesn't give much to go on. Try adding logging to the onCreate.

Comment: Did you declare your service in the manifest ?

Comment: yes ı did. Thanks :-). But when facebook is opened on browser I get some voice the it cut. I get it on my logcat.  07-31 16:08:56.460: A/libc(663): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree
07-31 16:08:56.590: A/libc(663): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)